# Airflow API for updating dags

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, airflow

We have API given by Airflow to access dags present in the environment.

reference : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/DAG

When I paste the URL in the browser, I can see the details of the dags, but when I access it from AWS lambda, using requests library, I am getting Permission denied error:

> {'detail': None, 'status': 403, 'title': 'Forbidden', 'type':
> 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/PermissionDenied'}

I have added the necessary roles and policies to this lambda function, but still the error remains the same.